# Error in project - Uncaught ReferenceError: Raven is not defined

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I've started getting an error in chrome console `Uncaught ReferenceError: Raven is not defined`. I have no idea what it is referring to or where it came from. The error doesn't appear when I open the project in fireFox. Can someone shed some light on this?

Error:  `Message`

```
    Uncaught ReferenceError: Raven is not defined
        at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (sidekick.js:1)
        at f (extension-lib.js:1)
        at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (extension-lib.js:1)
        at Function.ready (extension-lib.js:1)
        at HTMLDocument.xe (extension-lib.js:1)
    (anonymous) @   sidekick.js:1
    f   @   extension-lib.js:1
    fireWith    @   extension-lib.js:1
    ready   @   extension-lib.js:1
    xe  @   extension-lib.js:1
```

Comment: Please add the code in your question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It comes from the HubSpot Sales Chrome extension. If you remove it the error will go away.

Comment: Thanks. That's an hour I won't get back!